# KNN using Caret package giving bad results compared to other methods

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, r-caret, knn

I'm comparing a few different machine learning algorithms for automated essay scoring accuracy. The RMSE and RSquared values I'm getting for training sets are about 0.75 and 0.43 on average respectively. But for some reason when I run KNN using the same function framework I get RMSE=0.95 and RSquared=0.09. I'm not getting any error messages either so I don't know what's going wrong.

My data set is continuous and I'm performing regression on it.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
library(caret)

train_control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)

# Linear Regression ============================================================
lm <- train(holistic_score~., 
            data=training, 
            trControl=train_control, 
            method="lm")
lm$results
lm_pred <- predict(lm, testing)
postResample(pred = lm_pred, obs = testing$holistic_score)
# Train:  rmse = 0.714515   rsquared = 0.4737114
# Test:   rmse = 0.7508373  rsquared = 0.4423288

# K-NN =========================================================================
knn <- train(holistic_score~.,
             data=training,
             trControl=train_control,
             tuneLength=100,
             method="knn")
knn$results
knn_pred <- predict(knn, testing)
postResample(pred=knn_pred, obs=testing$holistic_score)
# Train:  rmse = 0.9466202  rsquared = 0.07567549
# Test:   rmse = 0.9512989  rsquared = 0.0966448
```

I'm only showing linear regression but I'm using 10 different algorithms on 6 different data sets and across the board KNN is doing much worse compared to the rest.

I've tried looking online at the documentation and here but I haven't found anything that solves my problem or mentions it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303475/error-using-caret-package-with-knn-method-something-is-wrong-all-the-accur) is the closest I've found to someone with a similar problem but it doesn't apply to me because I'm not using categorical predictors.

Does anyone know what could cause this?

**Edit:**
Here is a histogram of the dependent variable (holistic_score):

[image]

Comment: is it possible to share the dataset? my guess is that there is some weird distribution in the dependent variable

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the dataset - What would constitute a weird distribution?

Comment: Ok i noticed one thing, you did not scale the data. For knn, this is important, because you want the independent variables to be on the same scale for grouping

Comment: Most likely not the dependent. Try your knn with train(...,preProc = c("center", "scale"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you did not scale your independent variables for knn, this is crucial when your independent variables are on different scales. You can see a interesting discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287425/why-do-you-need-to-scale-data-in-knn):

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)
data = BostonHousing

train(medv ~.,data=data,method="knn",
trControl=trainControl(method="cv",number=3))

Summary of sample sizes: 337, 338, 337 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  k  RMSE      Rsquared   MAE     
  5  6.721722  0.4748246  4.625845
  7  6.897760  0.4429380  4.720363
  9  6.807877  0.4550040  4.654680

train(medv ~.,data=data,method="knn",
trControl=trainControl(method="cv",number=3),
preProc = c("center", "scale"))

Pre-processing: centered (13), scaled (13) 
Resampling: Cross-Validated (3 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 337, 338, 337 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  k  RMSE      Rsquared   MAE     
  5  4.873476  0.7354566  3.120004
  7  4.983704  0.7280253  3.125164
  9  4.972269  0.7348006  3.172021

train(medv ~.,data=data,method="glmnet",
trControl=trainControl(method="cv",number=3))

  alpha  lambda      RMSE      Rsquared   MAE     
  0.10   0.01355531  4.994509  0.7145962  3.483945
  0.10   0.13555307  4.997304  0.7145864  3.466551
  0.10   1.35553073  5.124558  0.7054928  3.504224
  0.55   0.01355531  4.995748  0.7145269  3.483881
  0.55   0.13555307  5.030863  0.7112925  3.463395
  0.55   1.35553073  5.423348  0.6793556  3.745830
  1.00   0.01355531  4.998020  0.7143324  3.482485
  1.00   0.13555307  5.084050  0.7055959  3.485051
  1.00   1.35553073  5.593417  0.6725029  3.904954
```

Comment: I found Euclidean distance not to be optimal in most cases. [kknn](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kknn/versions/1.3.1/topics/kknn) is a good package that uses Minkowski distance with arbitrary parameter. It is implemented in [caret](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/models/files/kknn.R) . This function also allows weighing of neighbors according to their distance.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @missuse. I haven't use it much, but I suppose you would need to scale the variables too?

Comment: @Sean, check out comment by missuse? could be useful for you

Comment: It might be less important due to weighting. However I did not test so I am not sure. I scaled them always prior knn.